# ¿Cómo vaciar un input type="number" en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, script

Cómo puedo vaciar un `input number` en JavaScript.

¿Se puede utilizar `document.innerHTML = number;`? o ¿cómo se hace?

Answer (score 1):

### Presentaré dos (02) formas de hacerlo

Si bien, la pregunta hace referencia de cómo se borra con **JavaScript** el campo numérico, no está demás mencionar que existen dos formas de hacerlo.

La primera opción, obviamente, no requiere de **JavaScript**.

**Por ejemplo:**

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="number" />
  <button type="reset">Limpiar</button>
</form>
```

Porque el campo numérico se encuentra dentro del formulario y en el formulario se encuentra el botón `reset`.

Mientras que la segunda opción se puede hacer utilizando **JavaScript.**

**Por ejemplo:**

```js
limpiar.onclick = () => {
  numero.value = "";
};
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numero" />
<button id="limpiar">Limpiar</button>
```

Si queremos que nuestro código sea compatible con una versión un poco más antigua de **JavaScript**, por ejemplo, *ECMAScript 5* podríamos definirla así:

```js
"use strict";

var numero = document.getElementById("numero"),
    limpiar = document.getElementById("limpiar");

limpiar.onclick = function () {
  numero.value = "";
};
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numero" />
<button id="limpiar">Limpiar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que utilizar `value`:

```js
document.getElementById("elIdDelInput").value = "";
```

Comment: No me funciona con .value y no se como hacerlo, es que el input number no me deja cambiar nada.

Comment: cual es tu codigo html? la respuesta que te di funciona para lo que necesitas, capaz estas colocando el Id del input mal. Actualiza la pregunta con tu codigo html.

Comment: No, lo coloqué bien, pero ya encontré la solución. lo puse en una función aparte. MUCHAS GRACIAS!!!

Answer (score 0):

Una forma rápida y corta sería esta... asignarle un ID a tu input:

```
<input type="number" id="input_vaciar" value="12312313"/>
```

Y luego puedes vaciarla así:

```
$('#input_vaciar').val('');
```

Y si necesitas guardar algun dato específico luego al hacer una acción, sería así:

```
$('#input_vaciar').val(new_val);
```

(donde new_val puede ser un dato que seteaste asi en crudo o puede ser una variable que contenga un valor númerico como resultado de X acción)

Comment: Para que funcione este código, es requerido jQuery,